# How to show innerHTML of texarea after deleting existing content

Tags: javascript, textarea, innerhtml, onblur, onfocus

I am trying to hide and show the innerHTML of a textarea based on focus and blur. Its working well. But an issue is, when i delete the entered text the inside innerHTML is already there in the element but its not showing. Following is the issue replication steps:

1. Enter text inside the textarea
2. Select all the text and delete it
3. Then mouseout from the textarea
4. The innerHTML is not visible there in the browser
5. But innerHTML is visible in the elements when i check with browser inspect element

```js
let textarea = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");

for (i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++) {
  let innertext = textarea[i].innerHTML;

  textarea[i].addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
    e.target.innerHTML = "";
  })

  textarea[i].addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
    e.target.innerHTML = innertext;
  })
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">Test</textarea>
```

Comment: Step 4 is not happening for me. But in any case, you have something weird in the code. You capture the innerHTML in the `innerText` variable when the page loads, and after that, every time the textarea is blurred, you put that old value back. You are never using the entered value. Also, _"blur"_ !== _"mouseout"_

Comment: Although that is one problem, I feel there is more to it. @blex. textarea does not support `value` attribute according to MDN. Here it works perfectly fine. Also, innerText, innerHTML, and value are all giving different values.

Comment: Actually i just need to show the default text of texarea, eventhough the user deletes all the text of textarea

Comment: The original code used `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`, somewhere it got lost in the edits. The new code seems to work.

Comment: @TusharShahi Value should be used, attributes of the elements are different from the [element's interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement).

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to try it out while fixing the question format, and forgot to remove the `.value` I added; Reverted my changes

Comment: @Teemu I do not understand. I hope you have seen textarea's MDN docs where they mention value is not supported but then on the link you share they have mentioned value

Comment: @TusharShahi That means, that `value` property is not reflected to the corresponding attribute, `value` attribute is a custom attribute for the `textarea` element, but the interface has the said property. JS uses the interface, unless you're explicitly setting/getting an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is using placeholder:

```
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder='Test'></textarea>
```

```
let textarea = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");

for(i=0;i<textarea.length;i++) {
let innertext = textarea[i].placeholder;
    textarea[i].addEventListener("focus",(e)=>{
      console.log( e.target.placeholder);
  e.target.placeholder = '';
    });

    textarea[i].addEventListener("blur",(e)=>{
         e.target.placeholder = innertext;
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi Tushar Shashi, you are almost near of the solution. In your code, after deleting the content, onfocus delete of innerhtml not works. If you fix that also, it will be a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. Btw, have you considered using a placeholder? This looks like a usecase for that. https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/XWRJzNw?editors=1111 no need for any JS

Comment: Tushar Shashi, actually i tried it first, but it does not delete the placeholder when mouse hit in the textarea. I hope hiding the existing placeholder will be a better user experience than it existing even in the focus. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/rNmaYzE?editors=1111). Does this work for you. I am now using placeholder, so there is no ambiguity about value/innerHTML

Comment: Hi Tushar Shashi, i already tried the placeholder method. But i am looking for a code which can hide the placeholder when user focus the textarea. THanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it is not meet the expected behaviour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234368/discussion-between-ren-jitsm-and-tushar-shahi).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML` to change/retrieve the value of the `textarea`. The `innerHTML` property does not update in the browser once a change has been made to the `textarea`'s content.

```js
let textarea = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");

for (i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++) {
  let innertext = textarea[i].innerHTML;

  textarea[i].addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
    e.target.value = "";
  })

  textarea[i].addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
    e.target.value = innertext;
  })
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">Test</textarea>
```